# passing sparse arrays from matlab to Eigen (C++) and back to matlab?

Tags: c++, matlab, eigen

The following is a mex code that multiplies dense arrays g and G from matlab using Eigen. How do I do this when g is sparse?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include "mex.h"
using Eigen::MatrixXd;
using namespace Eigen;
/*gateway function*/
void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
        int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]) {

    int nRows=(int)mxGetM(prhs[0]);
    int nCols=nRows;

    double* g=mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
    double* Gr=mxGetPr(prhs[1]);

    Map<MatrixXd> gmap (g, nRows, nCols );
    Map<MatrixXd> Grmap (Gr, nRows, nCols );
    plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(nRows, nCols, mxREAL);
    Map<MatrixXd> resultmap (mxGetPr(plhs[0]), nRows, nCols); 

    resultmap = gmap*Grmap; 

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use these functions to pass sparse (compressed) double matrix between MATLAB and Eigen* :

```
#include "mex.h"
#include <Eigen/Sparse>
#include <type_traits>
#include <limits>

using namespace Eigen;

typedef SparseMatrix<double,ColMajor,std::make_signed<mwIndex>::type> MatlabSparse;


Map<MatlabSparse >
matlab_to_eigen_sparse(const mxArray * mat)
{
    mxAssert(mxGetClassID(mat) == mxDOUBLE_CLASS,
    "Type of the input matrix isn't double");
    mwSize     m = mxGetM (mat);
    mwSize     n = mxGetN (mat);
    mwSize    nz = mxGetNzmax (mat);
    /*Theoretically fails in very very large matrices*/
    mxAssert(nz <= std::numeric_limits< std::make_signed<mwIndex>::type>::max(),
    "Unsupported Data size."
    );
    double  * pr = mxGetPr (mat);
    MatlabSparse::StorageIndex* ir = reinterpret_cast<MatlabSparse::StorageIndex*>(mxGetIr (mat));
    MatlabSparse::StorageIndex* jc = reinterpret_cast<MatlabSparse::StorageIndex*>(mxGetJc (mat));
    Map<MatlabSparse> result (m, n, nz, jc, ir, pr);
    return result;
}

mxArray* 
eigen_to_matlab_sparse(const Ref<const MatlabSparse,StandardCompressedFormat>& mat)
{
    mxArray * result = mxCreateSparse (mat.rows(), mat.cols(), mat.nonZeros(), mxREAL);
    const MatlabSparse::StorageIndex* ir = mat.innerIndexPtr();
    const MatlabSparse::StorageIndex* jc = mat.outerIndexPtr();
    const double* pr = mat.valuePtr();

    mwIndex * ir2 = mxGetIr (result);
    mwIndex * jc2 = mxGetJc (result);
    double  * pr2 = mxGetPr (result);

    for (mwIndex i = 0; i < mat.nonZeros(); i++) {
        pr2[i] = pr[i];
        ir2[i] = ir[i];
    }
    for (mwIndex i = 0; i < mat.cols() + 1; i++) {
        jc2[i] = jc[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

- Reading and writing MATLAB/Octave sparse matrix adopted from [here](https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.2/Sparse-Matrices-with-Mex_002dFiles.html).
- Thanks to @chtz for their recommendations.

Comment: `MappedSparseMatrix` is deprecated. You should use `Map<SparseMatrix<double> >`. And for the parameter of `eigen_to_matlab_sparse` I recommend taking `const Ref<const SparseMatrix<double>,StandardCompressedFormat>&` as input.

Comment: Actually, compiling this is returning the following. I am quite new to Eigen and C++. Do you know what is causing this? Thanks so much

!/home/mharb/eigen/eigen-eigen-5a0156e40feb/Eigen/src/SparseCore/SparseMap.h:222:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 6 provided

Comment: It seems that this error is caused by the -largeArrayDims flag when compiling. The code actually, compiles fine without it but I get a runtime error of: Function "mxGetIr" is obsolete

Comment: After changing mwSize to int, the code compiles, but gives an unexpected result. I've updated the question... Thanks a lot!

Comment: I tested both `matlab_to_eigen_sparse` and `eigen_to_matlab_sparse` in Octave and they worked for me. But matrix multiplication is a different thing. Also I updated `eigen_to_matlab_sparse` if the problem is related to it ,although you didn't use it.

Comment: I had assumed that the matrix multiplication result didn't work because of the `matlab_to_eigen_sparse` function rather than a separate issue. I've re-accepted the answer and edited the post indicating that it worked. Thank you very much and my apologies. 

I actually did try your function as is (i.e. before adapting it) and it did not compile for me until I changed mwSize and mwIndex to int.

Comment: Really?  I'm not sure but if you are sure that if MATLAB uses 16 bytes aligned storage for double arrays it is better to use `Map<MatrixXd, Aligned>` and  `Map<SparseMatrix<double> ,Aligned>` to enable full speed vectorization of eigen. Sometimes because of unaligned storage the application may [crash](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicUnalignedArrayAssert.html).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169524/discussion-between-avgn-and-rahnema1).

Comment: @avgn: What version of MATLAB are you using? `mwSize` and `mwIndex` were introduced quite a while back, and are 64-bit values on 64-bit platforms. You cannot replace them with `int` unless you use `-compatibleArrayDims` (which is actually still the default?).

Comment: @CrisLuengo I am using R2017b. I've updated the question with the error it gives when I compile it.